Remove the day from a date in SAS format
I have a dataset with dates in SAS format, for example: 01OCT2019. Is there a way to remove "01" from the date? I tried to format the date using monyy7. but it doesn't work.
Thank you in advance.
Best

Displaying the value with MONYY7. will NOT display the 01.  So why did that not work for you?  Are you asking how to convert any day in October of 2019 into the same number?  If so use the INTNX() function with the MONTH interval and an offset of zero will convert any date in that month to the first day of the month.

SAS has two base data types, character and numeric. A variable that has a value of the SAS date 01OCT2019 is a numeric variable, with the underlying numeric value being a number representing the number of days since 01JAN1960.
Removing the 01 from 01OCT2019 doesn't make sense in the numeric context, if you formatted the value using monyy7. then underneath that format it is still held by SAS as the number of days since 01JAN1960. When the variable is printed or otherwise output, it will display as OCT2019.
To remove the 01 from your SAS date AND convert it to a character variable, you could use the PUT function:
data _NULL_;
  have = '01OCT2019'd;
  want = put(have, monyy7.);
  put want=;
run;

want=OCT2019

